# Pop-up appears when keeping a key pressed for more than a second while playing Diablo 3 on OS X

Tags: diablo-iii, macos

A couple of minutes ago, while playing, I began experiencing a strange issue: whenever I keep pressed for a second or more some of the keys, a pop-up appears asking me to choose from a set of similar characters.

[image: A screenshot of the pop-up.]
[image: The pop-up appears even in the chat box.]
[image: And when I input my password, too.]

Some considerations regarding this issue:

- I never ever encountered it before today.
- I installed Diablo 3 on day one, and never had any issue with it (~30 hours of gameplay to date).
- The problem began in the middle of a gaming session, an hour and an half from the start.
- I didn't install anything or changed any setting, neither in the game nor in OS X.
- The pop-up seems belonging to OS X, because of its look and the fact that it can't be screenshotted neither by the game nor the operating system.
- I could not find any setting that could be related to this in "Keyboard" or "Universal access" in "System preferences".
- I don't know if I hit some voodoo key combo while playing.
- I already tried the classical help desk solutions (close and reopen the game, restart the computer, etc) to no avail.
- It does not happen with other applications (e.g. Firefox, Terminal).

Comment: It looks like an [IME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method_editor). Have you checked that it *only* happens when playing Diablo 3? Because if it happens outside the game too (and based on your description, it sounds like it should), this is off-topic for this site; you'll have more luck on [the Apple SE site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Michael Madsen, it's the first time I've seen something like that, so I'm still investigating it. I too think that's something placed by OS X, however it never happened to me before during my ~2 years with Apple. :S

Comment: what happens when you press a number that is shown there in gray?

Comment: Novarg, it inserts that character.

Comment: @Albireo are you using multiple keyboard layouts?

Comment: Novarg, I have Italian and Kotoeri (Hiragana and Katakana) enabled, however they've always been enabled since when I got my Mac (~2 years ago).

Comment: @Albireo does any of these layout give the same result in other apps? If so, try switching the layout to the other one in game

Comment: This is a new feature that was added in 10.7. I'll post an answer with screenshots when I get home, but it is 100% OS X and nothing at all to do with D3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/, but what you're actually seeing here is that the text entry system that Diablo uses is "well-behaved". (FireFox's text entry system probably isn't, on account of being cross-platform, and Terminal isn't for similar reasons.)

This question has the opposite problem, but should be illuminating. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35576

**Edit:** After a review of the screen shots it appears it might not be as well-behaved as I thought, if it happens outside of areas dedicated for text entry.

From the linked question; fix by opening Terminal.app and running the following command:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool FALSE
```

Comment: Care to elucidate the down vote?